# VB columed profile/process list with embedded sqllite database for editable process parameters

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, sqlite, gridview

I have no idea how to make this in Visual Studio 2010. I'm trying to make a program that has a "grid" with columns. It will have a option to name a new profile/process, which is then added to the grid/list.
I can then edit the profile/process by clicking a button and editing the parameters that the process runs with.

most of the time these processes are the same same program/executable, just multi-instanced.

I can then start the process with the given parameters after I have setup it's profile.

I want to be able to monitor the RAM/CPU usage in one of the colums of the record/profile/process, sort of like the task manager and also "maintain" the process and keep it running/restart automatically it so it doesn't stop or crash unless directed otherwise.

I want these profiles/process parameters to be stored in a sqllite dll embedded database.

I would appreciate your help. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The very first step is for you to get all process, then place it in a container.

From there you can rename the process via **My.Computer.FileSystem.RenameFile(file ,newName)**

I prefer using datagridview, as with it you can easily add/remove columns and refer to the data. Assuming you have a datagridview with one column:

```
         For Each ito As Process In Process.GetProcesses
              Datagridview1.rows.add(ito.ProcessName.ToString) 
         Next
```

this will get you through the first part.

Comment: So your suggesting something like this? [link]http://www.sourcecodester.com/tutorials/visual-basic-net/5820/displaying-computer-information-using-visual-basicnet.html[/link] That's okay but I want to be able to rename the processes, and also edit parameters of the processess and I want to only see a SPECIFIC process not all of them. And also launch, run, restart, stop, the same process.

Comment: What I mean by rename the process is not that. I mean make a profile name for the process not rename the process itself.

Comment: Here is what I have already but none of the buttons work. http://i.imgur.com/ilMnMZr.png